# reading dynamically created cookie names

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, cookiestore

i have a set of top messages that serve as alerts. They have an *X* to close them. Closing them sets a cookie that make them disappear forever, the name of the cookie is taken from the `id` of the specific top message you close.

i have a base code for creating, reading and erasing the cookie which goes like this:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
        c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

and i create the dynamic-named cookies like this:

```
if ($(".timed-top-message").size() > 0) {
    $(".timed-top-message").on("click", "i", function() {
        var CookieUniqueIdentifier = $(this).parent().attr("id")
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(200);

        createCookie(CookieUniqueIdentifier, 'true', 100000)
        console.log('cookie created');
    });
}
```

and this does the job. My problem is when i have to read the cookie. This throws an error:

```
(function() {
    var checkForCookiez = readCookie(CookieUniqueIdentifier); // i read the cookie
    if (!checkForCookiez) { // if it doesn't exist
        console.log('it does not exist')
    } else{ // if it does exist
        console.log('it does exist')
    }
})();
```

the error is

`app.js:1142 Uncaught ReferenceError: CookieUniqueIdentifier is not defined`

i get that `CookieUniqueIdentifier` is scoped inside a click function, and it can't retrieve it. But what i want to achieve is a system to dinamically creating cookies named by a unique `id` and consequently read them in a dynamic way.

I'm not very good with jquery and i was wondering if I'm on the right path or not. any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error your getting? Note you have a syntax error in the `console.log` statement contains a `'`

Comment: @JavaKungFu just updated the question

Comment: I see 2 options here. Option 1: Keep a array in scope of the IDs of cookies saved. Option 2: Use `document.cookie` to retrieve the list of all cookies and iterate. Of course option 1 wouldn't persistent across sessions so might not be ideal.

Comment: Can you use `$(this).parent().attr("id")` inside your click handler function - is it the same element?

Comment: @JavaKungFu it's there already

Comment: At the time you read the cookie I mean. What triggers the reading of the cookie? Can it be bound to the same element ID?

Comment: no no, it must be on page load

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here would be to read the cookie before showing the alert message(s) (on page load) and only show the alert if the cookie does not exist. You haven't shown that part of the code but if you include it I'd be happy to add the relevant  code updats here.

Comment: thanks for your help but i think you're off track. :(